# Provisioning Service Fabric behind Application Gateway

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-virtual-network

We are tying to achieve this.
From my understanding, we should place the outside interface of the SF loadbalancer on a private network and then connect to the App Gateway's LB internal interface using Azure Virtual Network Peering.

Is this doable, are there any issues with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's doable. There are multiple approaches you could go with -

1. Deploy App Gateway pointing at sf nodes directly, like shown here - [Fine Granular Microservices Load Balancing with Azure Service Fabric and Application Gateway](http://gonzowins.com/2016/02/28/servicefabircapplicationgateway/)
2. Deploy App Gateway pointing at [SF LB](https://blog.nilayparikh.com/azure/services/cloud-architecture-pattern-azure-service-fabric-and-microservices-part-1-physical-architecture/)

Catches:

- There are [limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits?toc=%2fazure%2fapplication-gateway%2ftoc.json#application-gateway-limits) around 
  how many Backend Address Pools you could have(up to 20), and how many machines and http settings each pool could run with. So, for instance, if you have SF cluster with the thousands 
  of services hosted at different ports, think through using SF LB and SF Reverse Proxy.
- Azure Application Gateway requires its subnet. When creating a virtual network, ensure that you leave enough address space to have multiple subnets. Once you deploy an application
  gateway to a subnet, only additional application gateways can be added to the subnet.
- While digging into your question, I've found out that App Gateway might not play nice with websockets under certain circumstances. Check out 
  [Communication through Azure Application Gateway blocked for WebSocket traffic](https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/421) for the details.

**P.S.**

If SF LB of yours is public you don't need VNET peering. The same works for private SF LB and Application Gateway installed into the same VNET.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is better support to abstract Service Fabric by using Azure API management instead of Application Gateway.

I presume your SF is on Azure then API management has built in support for Service fabric so you dont have to do end point resolution or get partition key etc

Comment: that's a great suggestion,  But dont I still need to place the Azure SF entry on a private Vnet?

Comment: Yes the SF and API management have to be on the same vnet. Just in case you going with that API management does have different pricing tier only the highest one have Vnet feature you need for all built in feature. We dont use singal R currently so I am not sure. :) Will do a POC just to see.